# PrimeNG tree not working with observable async

Tags: primeng, ngrx-store

I have a working implementation of [primeNG tree](https://www.primefaces.org/primeng/#/tree) control

I am now* modifying my code to use [ngrx/store](https://github.com/ngrx/store) and need to bind observable dataset

```
<p-tree [value]="folders$ | async" ></p-tree>
```

I get following error

```
TypeError: Cannot add property parent, object is not extensible
at UITreeNode.ngOnInit (tree.js:56)
at checkAndUpdateDirectiveInline (core.es5.js:10759)
at checkAndUpdateNodeInline
```

Although if i use p-accordian of p-datatable control, it seems to be working fine.

Not sure what is the problem here

Answer (score 0):

Turns out I was using ngrx-store-freeze in my dev-environment - and that prevents state from being mutated and p-tree indeed changes the state internally.

Posting as reference, in case anyone faces the same issue